# What methods are commonly used to remove a rusted and stuck rear wheel hub and bearing assembly?

Tags: wheel-bearing, rear, wheel-hub

I have a 2000 hyundai accent and I'm currently unable to remove the wheel hub and bearing assembly on one side due to rust. I'm so close to the finish line, but I am already over budget due to needing to buy additional tools when I encountered rusted lug nuts from hell. I need a cheap way to finish this job without disassembling the drum brakes, because I know from experience that I don't have the tools to get that back together.

What options do I have, assuming I was to figure this out on my own?

Here's what I've tried already:

- Banged the hell out of it.
- Lowered hub onto a concrete block, attempting to use the force of the car to loosen this in some way
- Banged the hell out of it again.

Help is appreciated! (not my vehicle below, but the same vehicle).

[image: I don't own this car, but this is the exact model]

**UPDATE:** I've selected an answer below: **Slide Hammer**. It came off in ONE hit. Thanks much!

Comment: Is this the style with a spindle nut or with bolts that go through the rear? Did you remove all the nuts/bolts? How big is your hammer? Pictures?

Comment: @Ben, It's the kind with a spindle nut. I've added an image. My hammer is average, but does have some weight. It should be noted, I've already done one side successfully, I just don't know how to overcome the rust on the other side.

Comment: Have you applied any penetrating oil to it? Heating the hub and hitting it with a hammer may help.

Comment: @TimNevins At the time, I didn't have either the oil or a torch but those are things I want to have on hand. I ended up getting a free tool loan (a slide hammer) from a store 2 miles down the road. Worked like a charm.

Comment: Success! Congratulations!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a job for a slide hammer - fixed to the hub and will apply the force directly in the most useful direction.

Comment: My thoughts exactly, a slide hammer is the perfect tool for the job. That and lots of penetrating fluid.

Comment: Slide hammer or a hub puller.

Comment: Going to AutoZone to rent one of these! Thanks everyone! I'll reply once I've given this a go.

Comment: Watch out where you put your fingers... the hammer does not feel pain...